# Formik React set values onChange with setFieldValue outside Array of Fields

Tags: reactjs, formik

**My goal** is to select a `Student` and with `onChange` to dynamically `setFieldValues` for the `FieldArray` of their nested `schedule` array of objects.

When I select Student: 1, I should get an array of fields for each of their 3 schedule items, Student 2: will have example 4 items. Example relates to something such as this [older example with Fruit on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryzkqkk6jm?file=/index.js).  [A second CodeSandbox also related for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-addremove-array-elements-example-forked-r374v).

**My problem** is that when I try to `map` a student's `schedule` it shows `schedule.map` is a TypeError. Thus not populating my `FieldArray` with the fields to be edited.

`TypeError: values.schedule.map is not a function`

**My JSON data**:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tom",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "class": "GYM",
          "time": "9:00,
        },
        {
          "class": "History",
          "time": "10:00",
        },
        {
          "class": "Lunch",
          "time": "11:00",
        },
      },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Nancy",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "class": "Math",
          "time": "9:00,
        },
        {
          "class": "Science",
          "time": "10:00",
        },
        {
          "class": "English",
          "time": "11:00",
        },
        {
          "class": "History",
          "time": "12:00",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

**My Formik Component**:

```
    const NewStudentSchedule = () => {
      const [studentSchedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        const getSchedule = async () => {
          try {
            const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
              `/api/schedule/`
            );
            setSchedule(data.results);
            // console.log(data);
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        };
        getSchedule();
      }, [fetchContext]);
      
      const initialValues = {
         id: '',
         schedule: [
           {
             class: '',
             time: '',
           },
         ],
       };

    return (
      <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            resetForm();
          }}
        >
          {({
            isSubmitting,
            values,
            setFieldValue,
            handleChange,
            errors,
            touched,
          }) => (
            <Form>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6 mr-auto">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="status">STUDENT</label>
                    <Field
                      className="form-control"
                      as="select"
                      name="id"
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        handleChange(event);
                        const selectedTask = schedule.find(
                          (selectStudent) => selectStudent.id === event.target.value
                        );
                        setFieldValue(
                          `schedule.step`,
                          selectedTask.schedule.step
                        );
                      }}
                    >
                      <option value="" defaultValue disabled>
                        ...
                      </option>
                      {schedule &&
                        schedule.map((i) => (
                          <option key={i.id} value={i.id}>
                            {i.name}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                    </Field>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <h3 className="pt-3">CREATE SCHEDULE</h3>
                <FieldArray name="schedule">
                  {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                    <>
                      {values.schedule.length > 0 &&
                        values.schedule.map((task, index) => (
                          <div className="row" key={index}>
                            <div className="col-11">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                  <div className="form-group">
                                    <label
                                      htmlFor={`schedule.${index}.class`}
                                    >
                                      CLASS
                                    </label>
                                    <Field
                                      className="form-control"
                                      name={`schedule.${index}.class`}
                                      type="text"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col">
                                  <div className="form-group">
                                    <label
                                      htmlFor={`schedule.${index}.time`}
                                    >
                                      TIME
                                    </label>
                                    <Field
                                      className="form-control"
                                      name={`schedule.${index}.time`}
                                      type="text"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </div>  
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-1">
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                className="btn delete"
                                onClick={() => remove(index)}
                              >
                                Delete
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="btn add"
                        onClick={() => push({ class: '', time: '' })}
                      >
                        Add
                      </button>
                    </>
                  )}
                </FieldArray>
                <button
                  className="btn float-right mb-5"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                >
                  SUBMIT
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>

      )

}
```

Screenshots of my App:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one

It looks like you want to pre-populate a form with data fetched from the API. Also, you'd like the user to be able to switch between students (Tom and Nancy). In that case, you need to set all students' data inside Formik's `initialValues`. And when handling the class values inside the `<FieldArray>`, you need to ensure you are referring to the correct class *for that particular student.*

There are a few issues with your code, for example `studentSchedule` is never used and `schedule` is undefined. I went ahead and made some assumptions and came up with this solution below. It refers to the correct class by using *two* indexes inside the `<FieldArray>`: `selectedStudentIndex` and `taskIndex`

```
const App = () => {
  const [studentSchedule, setSchedule] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSchedule = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await getData();
        setSchedule(data.results);
        // console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getSchedule();
  }, []);

  return <ScheduleForm students={studentSchedule} />;
};

const ScheduleForm = ({ students }) => {
  const initialValues = {
    id: "",
    students
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({
        isSubmitting,
        values,
        setFieldValue,
        handleChange,
        errors,
        touched
      }) => {
        const selectedStudentIndex = values.students.findIndex(
          ({ id }) => id === values.id
        );
        return (
          <Form>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6 mr-auto">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="status">STUDENT</label>
                  <Field
                    className="form-control"
                    as="select"
                    name="id"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                      handleChange(event);
                      const selectedTask = students.find(
                        (selectStudent) =>
                          selectStudent.id === event.target.value
                      );
                      setFieldValue(
                        `schedule.step`,
                        selectedTask.schedule.step
                      );
                    }}
                  >
                    <option value="" defaultValue disabled>
                      ...
                    </option>
                    {values.students &&
                      values.students.map((i) => (
                        <option key={i.id} value={i.id}>
                          {i.name}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                  </Field>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h3 className="pt-3">CREATE SCHEDULE</h3>
              <FieldArray name={`students.${selectedStudentIndex}.schedule`}>
                {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                  <div>
                    {values.id !== "" &&
                      values.students[selectedStudentIndex].schedule.map(
                        (task, taskIndex) => (
                          <div className="row" key={taskIndex}>
                            <div className="col-11">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                  <div className="form-group">
                                    <label
                                      htmlFor={`students.${selectedStudentIndex}.schedule.${taskIndex}.class`}
                                    >
                                      CLASS
                                    </label>
                                    <Field
                                      className="form-control"
                                      name={`students.${selectedStudentIndex}.schedule.${taskIndex}.class`}
                                      type="text"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col">
                                  <div className="form-group">
                                    <label
                                      htmlFor={`students.${selectedStudentIndex}.schedule.${taskIndex}.time`}
                                    >
                                      TIME
                                    </label>
                                    <Field
                                      className="form-control"
                                      name={`students.${selectedStudentIndex}.schedule.${taskIndex}.time`}
                                      type="text"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-1">
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                className="btn delete"
                                onClick={() => remove(taskIndex)}
                              >
                                Delete
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )
                      )}
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn add"
                      onClick={() => push({ class: "", time: "" })}
                    >
                      Add
                    </button>
                  </div>
                )}
              </FieldArray>
              <button
                className="btn float-right mb-5"
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
              >
                SUBMIT
              </button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-lqedl?file=/index.js)

I'd be interested if anyone comes up with a simpler approach.